# When I do colima ssh I am still in my current working directory with just colima prompt

Tags: docker, colima

I don't know what is happening here, I thought I would be inside the VM.

Answer (score 1):

[colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) is a [docker-for-mac](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/) replacement, not a VM (*there is a VM inside both `colima` and `docker-for-mac` but that is not something you need to go into*).

`colima` will add itself as another [docker context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/) in your mac, and you can run `docker` commands as you are accustomed to.

If you find the need to ssh into colima.. it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71265221/how-to-ssh-into-the-colima-instance/71265260#71265260), but note: **THIS IS NOT SOMETHING YOU NEED TO DO NORMALLY**!