# How to SSH into the colima instance

Tags: docker, colima

Looking for the steps needed to SSH into `colima`, this is too new and the documentation is a bit scarce. I need to copy over the volumes, and running `scp` seems ideal.

Comment: if you want to copy a file inside a docker image you would like to do it another way I think.

Comment: @vinalti I have volumes with data inside docker-for-mac and i want to move them to colima for finish my transition.

Comment: But then you better mount the volume directly on your Mac and copy it directly from there.

Comment: I wanted to automate it, this was step one, this was step 2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71268183/how-to-migrate-volume-data-from-docker-for-mac-to-colima

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Quickest answer

`colima ssh`

### Quick-ish answer using `ssh`

```
(tmpconfig=$(mktemp); limactl show-ssh --format config colima > $tmpconfig; ssh -F $tmpconfig lima-colima)
```

While i'm at it, here is the `scp`:

```
(tmpconfig=$(mktemp); limactl show-ssh --format config colima > $tmpconfig; scp -F $tmpconfig lima-colima:/path/to/somewhere/ .)
```

*I would love to have written this with a file descriptor, unfortunately, ssh does not like it when you pass a file descriptor in the `-F` argument, such as: `ssh -F <(limactl show-ssh --format config colima) lima-colima`*

---

### Use root

If you need to auth as `root` such as `ssh -F $tmpconfig root@lima-colima` you'll notice it won't work, your user will always be used, here are the steps to change that.

```
(
tmpconfig=$(mktemp);
# Need to remove the 'ControlPath' and 'User', and add 'ForwardAgent'
(limactl show-ssh --format config colima | grep -v "^  ControlPath\|  ^User"; echo "  ForwardAgent=yes") > $tmpconfig;
# Setup root account
ssh -F $tmpconfig $USER@lima-colima "sudo mkdir -p /root/.ssh/; sudo cp ~/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"
)
```

The command above changes slightly to:

```
(tmpconfig=$(mktemp); (limactl show-ssh --format config colima | grep -v "^  ControlPath\|  ^User"; echo "  ForwardAgent=yes") > $tmpconfig; ssh -F $tmpconfig root@lima-colima)
```

---

### Using ~/.ssh/config

If you're going to be `ssh`-ing into `colima` a lot, you can alway just skip all the fuss and simply add it into your `~/.ssh/config` and just call it "normally".

```
# run this ONLY ONCE!!!
limactl show-ssh --format config colima >> ~/.ssh/config
```

And then just call `ssh`/`scp` "normally":

```
ssh lima-colima
scp lima-colima:/path/blah/foo .
```

*Personally, I don't like to clutter my `~/.ssh/config`, but do what best works for you.*

Comment: Note that `show-ssh` is deprecated: `WARN[0000] "limactl show-ssh" is deprecated. Instead, use "ssh -F /Users/username/.lima/colima/ssh.config lima-colima"`.