# How to get VM usage values with Colima?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, colima

How to check the actual stats for CPU and RAM usage with colima?

**Background**

Coming from docker-desktop for mac there is a UI tool which displays this information in its footer:

[image]

in Format: `RAM X.XXGB CPU X.XX%`

---

colima version 0.4.4

git commit: 8bb1101a861a8b6d2ef6e16aca97a835f65c4f8f

docker-desktop version: 4.10.1

Answer (score 2):

If you `ssh` into the `colima` instance, you can run `top` or `htop` or whatever you come up with.

```
(tmpconfig=$(mktemp); limactl show-ssh --format config colima > $tmpconfig; ssh -tF $tmpconfig lima-colima)
```

*[from a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71265221/how-to-ssh-into-the-colima-instance)*

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the documentation, this is the closest thing I could see:

`docker stats`

This does not show total usage. Instead, this shows a list of containers with CPU and memory consumptions.

Example output:

```
CONTAINER ID  NAME             CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O          BLOCK I/O   PIDS
178c82edfcfe  container-name   0.91%     264.5MiB / 7.767GiB   3.33%     27.6MB / 692kB   0B / 0B     12
```

Comment: What you mean is `colima status`? `colima stat` is no valid command on my side.

Comment: btw I also needed to observe a specific container's mem usage (using colima), so I ended up using this command to draw a graph with ttyplot:
`{ while true; do colima ssh cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/$(docker inspect -f "{{.Id}}" <container-name>)/memory.usage_in_bytes; sleep 0.3; done } | ttyplot`